# Error 401 en Método Get en Android

Tags: android, rest, kotlin

Tengo el siguiente problema cuando intento utilizar el método GET en Android,el problema es que me da error 401 que significa que no estoy autorizado a realizar esa petición pero el problema es que le estoy pasando como parámetro el token y aún así sigo teniendo el error.Aquí el código

```
val url = URL("https://10.58.10.193:8443/api/categoriaActividad/")
        val conn =url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection

        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + "78750372b5954a0ddbc5f904254498cb77431599")

        conn.connectTimeout = 1500
        conn.requestMethod = "GET"
        conn.doInput = true
        conn.doOutput = true
 conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json")
       val policy = StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)

        val responseCode = conn.responseCode
        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

            val `in` = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(
                    conn.inputStream) as Reader?)

            val sb = StringBuilder("")
            var line = `in`.readLine()

            while (line != null) {

                sb.append(line)

                break

            }

            `in`.close()

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, responseCode ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
```

Comment: Hola Angel iba agregar una respuesta pero en realidad llegaría a lo mismo, las credenciales de la petición son incorrectas, estas seguro que tu token no ha expirado? trata de realizar la petición GET con http://hurl.it y comenta que resultado tienes

Comment: [Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/android-studio/info): Utilizar esta etiqueta solo si la pregunta está asociada al uso, funcionalidades o problemas con el IDE.